# Express Static for Authenticated Users

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath

How can I enable static directories just for a user's session in express? Using some HTML files as an examples, I know I can serve a directory called private via the call below

```
app.use("/private", express.static(appDir + '/private'));
```

What I would like to do is just enable the static resource once a user has been authenticated (using stormpath as my example).

For example, the function below would check if the user existed in stormpath and if they did, the app would then serve the static directory of maps.

```
app.get('/getPrivate', stormpath.getUser, function(req, res) {
    if(req.user){
      app.use("/private", express.static(appDir + '/private'));
      res.redirect('/private/index.html');      
    }else{
      //your not logged in.... redirect to login page      
    }
});
```

This does not work as I've found once I enable the static directory for a user, another user would then be able to visit the private directory without logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using app.all in my routes did the trick

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

app.all('/private/*', stormpath.getUser, function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user){      
       next();      
    }else{
      //you are not logged in.... redirect to login page
      res.redirect('/');            
    }
});

app.use("/private", express.static(appDir + '/private'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to require authentication for a route, you should use `stormpath.loginRequired`.  If the user is not logged in, they will be redirected to the login page.

Comment: I guess this is more of an express question. I am comfortable with the Stormpath part and just want to enable static content for users that have been authenticated. All my content has already been generated in html and I'd like to serve it statically.